# MATLAB: How to define FontSize for Ticks on Axes when printing figures to files

Tags: matlab, printing, font-size, figure, axes

I'm currently working on a figure generation tool for an app I'm writing.
In that regard, I'm trying to change the size of the ticks on the axes, but every time i save the figure, the font size of the ticks changes to a default value.
Is there a way to prevent this?
Code below:

```
F=figure('PaperPositionMode','manual','visible',false);
AX = gca;

% PLOT SOME STUFF (omitted here, since no relevance)

F.Resize = 'off';
F.Units = 'points';
F.PaperUnits = 'points';
AX.Units = 'points';
AX.Clipping = 'on';
AX.DataAspectRatioMode = 'auto';
AX.PositionConstraint = 'innerposition';
AX.FontSizeMode = 'manual';

% CHANGE PROPERTIES OF AX AND F

AX.XAxis.FontSize = 32;

% When executing next line, the font size of the ticks on the XAxis will change back to 10. 
print(F,'CurrentFigure.png','-dpng','-r0');

% Changing AX.FontSize will not solve the problem.
% Changing interpreter will not solve the issue.
% Changing renderer will not solve the issue.
```

Basically I've read through every single property of the figure class, the axes class and the numeric-ruler class. I can't find any option that keeps the font size of the ticks when saving the figure to a file.
If I use the exportgraphics (https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exportgraphics.html) function instead of the print function, the tick size stays the same. But exportgraphics crops the image, which completely ruins the purpose of the program in this case. So I can't use that function.

Here is a small script that will produce the error described.

```
% Figure Parameters
FigWidth = 2212;     % Outer position
FigHeight = 1030;    % Outer position

% Generate some data:
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
y = cos(x);
yy = sin(x);

% Create figure
f = figure;
ax = axes;
f.Resize = 'off';
f.Units = 'points';
f.PaperUnits = 'points';
ax.Units = 'points';
ax.Clipping = 'on';
ax.DataAspectRatioMode = 'auto';
ax.FontSizeMode = 'manual';
ax.PositionConstraint = 'innerposition';
f.PaperPositionMode = 'auto';
f.OuterPosition = [100 100 FigWidth FigHeight]*72/96;
f.PaperPosition = [100 100 FigWidth FigHeight]*72/96;
ax.InnerPosition = [150 150 FigWidth-325 FigHeight-320]*72/96;

% Plot shizzle
plot(ax, x, y)
yyaxis right
plot(ax, x, yy)
yyaxis left
legend(ax)
ax.XGrid = 'on';
ax.XMinorGrid = 'on';
ax.YGrid = 'on';
ax.YMinorGrid = 'on';

% Change figure parameters
xlim([x(1) x(end)])
ax.XAxis.Label.String = 'X-Axis';
ax.YAxis(1).Label.String = 'Y-Axis';
ax.YAxis(2).Label.String = 'YY-Axis';
ax.YAxis(2).Label.Color = ax.YAxis(1).Label.Color;

ax.Title.String = 'Title';

LabelFontsize = 32;
ax.Title.FontSize = 32;
TicsFontSize = 30;
ax.Legend.FontSize = 30;

ax.XAxis.Label.FontSize = LabelFontsize;
ax.YAxis(1).Label.FontSize = LabelFontsize;
ax.YAxis(1).FontSize = TicsFontSize;
ax.YAxis(2).FontSize = TicsFontSize;
ax.XAxis.FontSize = TicsFontSize;
ax.YAxis(2).Label.FontSize = LabelFontsize;
pause(2)
print(f,'CurrentFigure.png','-dpng','-r0');
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, font size are chaging on my computer (Matlab R2020a). You might want to checkout [`export_fig`](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig). Can you provide a [mcve], maybe plotting is relevant.

Comment: @rinkert Yeah. I tried that one already. Some times it works, and some times it also rescales the tick size. So unfortunately it's not gonna solve my problem. I'll post a plotting example in a sec.

Comment: @rinkert I've updated the question with a script that illustrates the error described.

Comment: Can reproduce with this example, seems to be happening only when the figure is larger than my screen resolution.

Comment: Yes. Same issue on my end. Though no errors or warnings.